# Disable automatic scroll down when pressing space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website where pressing space starts a timer, but pressing space apart from starting the timer scrolls the page all the way down. I would like to know how to disable this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers **must** be in English. See [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content), and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a default browser behaviour. we can prevent it by using `event.preventDefault();`

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 32 && event.target == document.body) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked